# Необходимо перевести SQL запрос в LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Доброго времени суток. Возникла проблема с переводом SQL запроса в LINQ.

Вот, собственно, SQL запрос.

`SELECT * FROM Books b JOIN Authors a ON b.RecordID = a.RecordID AND a.TeacherID = 6`

Необходимо перевести его в LINQ, но я, разобраться, к сожалению, так и не смог. Прошу помощи

Comment: А что сложного-то? Что вы пытались сделать и что не получается?

Comment: а ты пробовал Linqer http://www.sqltolinq.com ? это SQL-> LINQ конвертер. можно еще LINQPad юзать http://www.linqpad.net/

Comment: вам помогут операторы `Where()`, `Join()`. алгоритм может быть например следующим: фильтруем `Authors` по условию `TeacherId==6` делаем соединение с `Books`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Честно сказать незнаю сожет ли это переварить ОРМ...

```
Books
  .Join(
      Authors.Where(x => x.Author.TeacherID == 6),
      book => book.RecordID,
      author => author.RecordID,
      (book, author) => new 
        { 
            Book = book,
            Author = author
        }
   )
```